# Intersecting sublists in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, transpose

I have the following two lists

```
l1 = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 14}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 
    1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 2}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 3}};
l2 = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 40}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 50}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 60}};
```

and I need to extract items from l2 whose date (the first element of each l2 element) matches dates in l1 (so as to produce two lists of exactly the same length)

I don't see why something like:

```
Select[l1, MemberQ[Transpose[l2][[1]], #[[1]]]]
```

should produce an empty list. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Although my response is correct and was first, Sjoerd spotted the issue in your code (the missing ampersand) and thus gave a better answer to your question, in my view. So feel free to change your selection.

Comment: radrat, I agree with David.  Sjoerd is the one who answered your actual question, and I feel that it deserves your Accept.  I posted what I feel is the cleanest method, and I hope it is helpful, but replies like David's and mine are ancillary to the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possibly what you have in mind?

```
dates=Transpose[l2][[1]];
Cases[l1, {x_, _} /; MemberQ[dates, x]]
```

Comment: Hi David, that did it (actually with a small change: it should be l2 in the first line) , thanks for the prompt reply! I am still baffled as to why my approach is not working though

Comment: @David Notice, that this solution also evaluates Transpose for every element of x. This can be seen by evaluating `Cases[l1, {x_, _} /; MemberQ[Print[1]; Transpose[l2][[1]], x]]`. There will be 5 numbers printed at execution.

Comment: Sasha is right, your new form is not equivalent the prior one, if that was your intention.  You would need an `Evaluate` in there: `Cases[l1, {x_, _} /; MemberQ[Evaluate[Transpose[l2][[1]]], x]]`

Comment: @Sasha MemberQ seems to check each element in l1 separately.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  But putting the `Evaluate` in does not change things: try `Cases[l1, {x_, _} /; 
  MemberQ[Print[1]; Evaluate[Transpose[l2][[1]]], x]]`   Nor does putting in the known value of `Transpose[l2[[1]]]`: e.g.,  `Cases[l1, {x_, _} /; 
  MemberQ[Print[1]; {{2011, 3, 13}, {2011, 3, 16}, {2011, 3, 17}}, x]]`  So I would conclude that it's `MemberQ` that works by looping through each value of x, regardless.

Comment: When you say "does not change things" do you mean `Timing` results, or something else?

Comment: @Mr. I mean that if you insert `Print[1];` to the right of `MemberQ[` you will see it print out `1` five times before producing the desired result.

Comment: @David But you should have included `Print` inside `Evaluate`. Then the argument of MemberQ would be evaluated and then resulting pattern will be used for every element of `l1`. This way you would evaluate `Transpose` once. Otherwise `Condition`, i.e. `/;` holds its arguments, and `MemberQ` with its arguments would only be evaluated after pattern matcher found `x` and this evaluation will be repeated for every match, i.e. for every element of `l1`

Comment: @Sasha (and Mr. Wizard) I rolled back to an earlier version, where data is computed first and handed off to MemberQ. Does this avoid multiple calls to `Transpose`?

Comment: @Mr. Ah!!!  Now I get it. Inside `Evaluate`, to indicate how many times `Transpose` was `Evaluate`d.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the ampersand. It should be

```
Select[l1, MemberQ[Transpose[l2][[1]], #[[1]]]&]
```

Comment: You may realize this, but this evaluates `Transpose[l2][[1]]` for every element of `l1`. It is better to use `Select[l1, MemberQ[Evaluate[Transpose[l2][[1]]], #[[1]]]&]`

Comment: @Sash Yep, this seemed to me the only answer to the question what was wrong. Note that the OP didn't ask for an alternative, just an explanation why his own method didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Sjoerd shows you how to make your method work, but it is not optimal.  The problem is that `Transpose[l2][[1]]` is evaluated again for every element in `l1`.  David give a method which does that step only once.  You could also use:

```
Cases[l1, {Alternatives @@ l2[[All, 1]], _}]
```

Comment: +1 Really nice. First time I've seen `Alternatives Apply`'d like that.

Answer (score 3):

A faster method for when your lists get bigger:

```
DeleteCases[GatherBy[Join[l1, l2], First], {_}][[All, 1]]

(*  Out= {{{2011, 3, 13}, 40}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 50}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 60}}  *)
```

If your list might contain duplicates, you can use the

`l1 = GatherBy[l1, First][[All, 1]]`

to remove the duplicates first.

Comment: This does not produce the same result.

Comment: I changed the Part spec to match.  Thanks for catching that @TomD.

Comment: @TomD I am sorry, but I do not see any declaration that the lists have no duplicates within the first elements, either in the question, or in this answer.  Without that, this is not a solution.  Consider:  `l1 = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "d"}, {2, "x"}};
l2 = {{1, "q"}, {3, "r"}};`  or:  `l1 = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, "d"}};
l2 = {{5, "q"}, {5, "r"}, {2, "s"}};` -- neither gives the correct result, in my opinion.

Comment: @Mr.  L2 is a list of dates and unlikely to contain duplicates.  If so, all solutions fail as they do not "produce two lists of exactly the same length".  If L1 contains duplicates, and this is a concern, they can be easily removed?. IMHO, Joshua's approach is quite a nice one, illustrating a use of GatherBy, and works for the example given by the OP.

Comment: @TomD okay, now someone needs to make an edit so I can reverse my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my non-sorting intersection code:

```
NonSortingIntersection[l1_, l2_, test_: SameQ] := 
 Module[{res = 
    Last@Reap[
      Scan[Extract[l1, 
         Position[l1, x_ /; test[x, #], {1}, 1, Heads -> False], 
         Sow] &, l2]]}, If[res === {}, res, First[res]]]
```

Here is the usage:

```
In[22]:= NonSortingIntersection[l1, l2, 
 Function[{x, y}, First[x] == First[y]]]

Out[22]= {{{2011, 3, 13}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 2}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 3}}
```

Notice that unlike other solutions the output is guaranteed to have length no longer that that of `l2`. For instance:

```
In[24]:= Cases[Join[l1, l1], {x_, _} /; MemberQ[Evaluate[Transpose[l2][[1]]], x]]

Out[24]= {{{2011, 3, 13}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 2}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 
  3}, {{2011, 3, 13}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 2}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 3}}

In[25]:= NonSortingIntersection[Join[l1, l1], l2, 
 Function[{x, y}, First[x] == First[y]]]

Out[25]= {{{2011, 3, 13}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 2}, {{2011, 3, 17}, 3}}
```

This may or may not be desirable, but this is up to radhat who knows his problem better.